# Форма с select, в которой option соответствует выбранному элемениту из массива

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Есть массив:

```
let mas = [{
    "лето": "Одень футболку и шорты"
  },
  {
    "осень": "Одень куртку и штаны"
  },
  {
    "зима": "Одень шубу и тёплые штаны"
  },
  {
    "весна": "Одень ветровку и джинсы"
  },
]
```

Помогите с созданием формы с `select`, в которой `option` соответствует выбранному элементу из массива. Когда выбираешь определённый `option` установить в `input type=text` соответствующую времени года строку.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так :

```js
let d = document.getElementById('doc');
let i = document.getElementById('testInput');

let mas = [{
    "лето": "Одень футболку и шорты"
  },
  {
    "осень": "Одень куртку и штаны"
  },
  {
    "зима": "Одень шубу и тёплые штаны"
  },
  {
    "весна": "Одень ветровку и джинсы"
  },
];

let select = document.createElement('select');
mas.forEach(e => {
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  let key = Object.keys(e)[0];
  let text = e[key];

  option.value = text;
  option.text = key;
  select.add(option);
});

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  i.value = this.value;
});
d.appendChild(select);
```

```html
<div id='doc'></div>
<input type="text" id="testInput">
```

Я создал `select`, в который накидал по одному элементу `option` для каждого элемента в массиве, как `value` был использован текст, как `text` ключ обьекта, при изменении значения в селекте, просто закидываем его `value` в `value` инпута.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mas = {
    "лето": "Одень футболку и шорты",
    "осень": "Одень куртку и штаны",
    "зима": "Одень шубу и тёплые штаны",
    "весна": "Одень ветровку и джинсы",
  }
function proverkaVremeniGoda() {
  var vremya = document.getElementById("vremyaGoda").value
  var a="";
  switch (vremya) {
    case "zima": {a = "зима"}
      break;
    case "leto": {a = "лето"}
      break;
    case "osen": {a = "осень"}
      break;
    case "vesna": {a = "весна"}
      break;      
  }
  document.getElementById("text").value=mas[a]
}
```

```html
<select onchange="proverkaVremeniGoda()" id="vremyaGoda">
  <option value="leto">Лето</option>
  <option value="zima">Зима</option>
  <option value="osen">Осень</option>
  <option value="vesna">Весна</option>
</select>
<br/>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```